# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, scrollview

I'm getting this error for a while, searched for solutions in here but got nothing to work. I'm trying to add the scrollview in my fragment programmatically which has a linearlayout as root element.

**my fragment layout xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#481327"
tools:context="com.gov.dmrd.disastermanagement.TestFragment3">

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment oncreateview**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    LinearLayout innerLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_fragment3, container, false);
    innerLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    innerLayout.setScrollBarStyle(LinearLayout.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_fragment3, container, false);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.personnel_name);
    rank = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.personnel_rank);
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(container.getContext());
        tv1.setText(name[i]);
        innerLayout.addView(tv1, params);
        TextView tv2 = new TextView(container.getContext());
        tv2.setText(rank[i]);
        innerLayout.addView(tv2, params);
    }
    sv.addView(innerLayout);
    return sv;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be
>   cast to android.widget.ScrollView

Because trying to cast `LinearLayout` to `ScrollView`

> I'm trying to add the scrollview in my fragment programmatically which
>   has a linearlayout as root element

Create `ScrollView` dynamically and add it to `innerLayout` :

```
   View view=(View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_fragment3,
                                                                 container, false);
    ScrollView sv =new ScrollView(getActivity()); //<< create ScrollView object
   LinearLayout innerLayout=new LinearLayout(getActivity());//<<create LinearLayout
    //...your code here
    sv.addView(innerLayout);
    view.addView(sv);
    return view;
```

Comment: Great answer! Understood the problem and worked perfectly too! Cheers! :D